# Eclipse plugin: Finding line numbers containing a substring not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using the following function to find all the line-numbers which has **word** as a substring.

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> find(String word, File text) throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(text));
    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try {
        String line = rdr.readLine();
        if (line.contains(word)) {        
            results.add(rdr.getLineNumber());
        }
    } finally {
        rdr.close();
    }
    return results;
}
```

But, when I call the above function as under, I get the size of the lineNumberList as 0 (Assume that the file contains at least one occurrence of **word** as substring )

```
IProject project = (IProject)((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
IFile manifest = project.getFile("AndroidManifest.xml");
File manifestfile = manifest.getRawLocation().makeAbsolute().toFile();
ArrayList<Integer> lineNumberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lineNumberList = find(PermissionInfo[0].trim(), manifestfile);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed via the debugger that you're actually getting the correct file content?

Comment: Printing the permissions of "manifest" in the table view is working fine. Is there anything wrong with "line.contains(word)"?

Comment: Are you sure that the file AndroidManifest.xml has line breaks? The LineNumberReader looks for line breaks.

Comment: The Manifest file has 33 lines. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the items i.e.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> find(String word, File text) throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(text));
    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try {
        String line = rdr.readLine();
        while(line != null){
        if (line.contains(word)) {        
            results.add(rdr.getLineNumber());
        }
        line = rdr.readLine();
        }
    } finally {
        rdr.close();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having multiple lines in the file, a for loop might be needed to wrap getLine().